# Create a current class for my dynamic menu

Tags: php, symfony1

Seems as creating a current class was harder than I thought :)

modules/menus/actions/components.class.php

```
$this->elements = array(
        "My page" => "content/index",
        "Admin" => "content/index",
    );

$this->current = "";
foreach($this->elements as $name => $link) {
    list($module, $action) = explode("/", $link);
    if ($this->getContext()->getModuleName() == $module && 
    $this->getContext()->getActionName() == $action) {
        $this->current = $name;
    }
}
```

modules/menus/templates/_main.php

```
if ($current == $name){
    echo link_to($name, $link, array("class" => "selected"));
}else {
    echo link_to($name, $link); 
}
```

If you look at the links, they go to "content/index" (for now).
The big problem is, that content/index redirects to auth/login, so the current module and action, even if the URL is showing content/index is auth/login.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just an idea:

1. Set `return` parameter when redirect to sign in page
2. Parse this parameter instead of actual url

Or:

1. Work with routes, not "module-action" pairs
2. Forward instead of redirecting to auth route
3. `$currentRouteName = $this->getContext()->getRouting()->getCurrentRouteName()`

Hope this helps.